# Use assembly language of ARM64-v8a on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, assembly, android-ndk, arm, java-native-interface

I am building an Android app with Android studio on `ARM64-v8a` which can ask for assembly functions.
After searching a lot of information online, I still cannot handle this problem.

> My `CMakeList.txt` is as following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

enable_language(ASM)
set(can_use_assembler TRUE)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
#add_definitions(-DANDROID -DNDEBUG -DOC_ARM_ASM)

set_source_files_properties(multiple.s PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-x 
assembler-with-cpp")

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
         native-lib

         # Sets the library as a shared library.
         SHARED

         # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
         src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
         src/main/cpp/multiple.s
         )
```

> The code of `multiple.s` is as

```
.session .text
.align  2
.global armFunction
.type   armFunction, %function

armFunction:
    @ Multiply by 10. Input value and return value in r0
    stmfd   sp!, {fp,ip,lr}
    mov r3, r0, asl #3  @ r3=r0<<3=r0*8
    add r0, r3, r0, asl #1  @ r0=r3+r0<<1=r0*8+r0*2=r0*10
    ldmfd   sp!, {fp,ip,lr}
    bx  lr
    .size   armFunction, .-armFunction
```

> The code from `native-lib.cpp` is as following:

```
extern "C"

int armFunction(int);

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_zyf_testarm_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    std::string hello = "Hello from C++ ";
    int x = 1;
    char info[1024] = "";
    x = x + armFunction(10);

    sprintf(info,"%d",x);
    return env->NewStringUTF(info); //hello.c_str()
}
```

And the error message is that

> error: unknown directive
>     .session .text
>
> error: unexpected token at start of statement
>         @ Multiply by 10. Input value and return value in r0

Those are just part of the error message. In fact, it shows that every instruction in `multiple.s` is `unknown`.

### Update:

> Someone points out that the problem might be `case sensitive`. So I tried to use another `.S` file named `main_asm.S`. 
>   The code of `main_asm.S` is as following:

```
.text
.global asm_main
 asm_main:
    mov r0, #1
    bx lr
```

The problems are still there:

> Unknown instruction

### Update:

I raise up another question [Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50059084/fail-to-run-an-example-code-which-can-run-assembly-code-in-android-app).

I think the problem is caused by the same reason. Maybe my `clang` is not working well? I don't know, please help : )

Thanks a lot for helping me to solve this problem : )

Comment: Might be case sensitive, many of the examples use upper-case `.S`

Comment: _"session"_ <-- Did you mean se**ct**ion?

Comment: @Michael Yes, I think you are right. It should be **section**. But still not working after change `.session` to `.section`.

Comment: @RichardCritten It's still not working by using a `.S` file. The details of the file is updated in the question.

Comment: Just to be sure; have you set `abiFilters` to only include arm64-v8a?

Comment: @Michael I think I didn't set `abiFilters`. Where should I edit the code?

Comment: In the `defaultConfig { ndk {} }` block. You should set `abiFilters` to only those ABIs that you want to build for, otherwise your native libraries will be built for _every_ ABI (including x86, MIPS, etc). Or you could try conditionally adding the source files in your `CMakeLists.txt` [in this fashion](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk.git/+/8f13499df723afd76c2db2264b82ba3b131cb4ad/tests/build/build-assembly-file/CMakeLists.txt).

Comment: @Michael Sorry to inform you that it still does not work. I just add defaultConfig { ndk {abiFilters "arm64-v8a"} } in my `build.gradle` file. Also I add a line in `CMakeList.txt` `set_target_properties(native-lib PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bx lr` and registers `r0..r15` are 32-bit ARM, not AArch64 / ARM64-v8a.  ARM64 registers are x0..31 (and their low halves are w0..31), and you return with `ret` (an alias for `br`)

Make sure a 64-bit build doesn't try to build 32-bit asm source files.
Or if you do have 32-bit asm sources, make sure you only do a 32-bit build.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem "unknown token/instruction/..." with Android Studio (V3.1.2) and solved it with abiFilters (in app/build.gradle) but without reference to ndk:

```
android {
...
    defaultConfig {
...
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
            }}}
...    
}
```

(maybe change armeabi-v7a for arm64-v8a)

hope it helps

(you can see the project here: https://github.com/denisb/GPerf)